# INDIRECT ADDRESS with QUERY to select offset result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a stylized table, not laid out like a database. Some rows contain titles, some rows contain data across various columns.

I would like a formula that will search Column A for all instances of "Title", then offset the results by a chosen number of rows and columns.

The data would look something like:

```
|  Title: | title1 |       |       |   
|   Data  | Value  | Data2 | Value2|
|         |        |       |       |   
|  Title: | titel2 |       |       |   
|   Data  | Value  | Data2 | Value2|
```

I'm trying to find all instances of "Title:" and return "Value2", specifically by using INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN()+3)) function in conjunction with QUERY.

I'd be happy with an alternative formula to INDIRECT ADDRESS, so long as I can select the number of rows and columns to offset.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be your desired output from given sample data?

Comment: If I'm being a bit more expansive than my original question, I'd like to look for any instance of "Title:" and select the "Value" and "Value2" from the next row. I would have thought using QUERY to select, then somehow modifying the results with INDIRECT ADDRESS would be the method.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I agree with player0. Seeing it in a sheet (with visible column and row data and some realistic sample data) would be more helpful. In addition, will you *only* want Value and Value2 (i.e., you don't want those paired with the title)? This seems odd to me as I imagine it with your dummy data, which brings me back around to the suggestion to share a link to a sheet with some *realistic* data in it, set up where and how it will actually be represented in your real-world spreadsheet.